# Read whether int or string using the file extraction operator

Tags: c++

I'm reading from a file and I am using the extraction operator to grab the first value. the problem is i need to know if the value is a int or a string so i can put it in the appropriate variable.

so my question is can I try to put it in an int and if it fails it'll throw it in a string? or check beforehand if its a int or a string?

I can provide code/psudocode if need be.

file example:

```
   3 rows  3 columns all @ go
        5 columns 6  rows go
        5     rows        triangular        go
alphabetical   3 rows    3       columns go
 all !  4 rows  4 columns outer     go
 alphabetical      triangular       outer      5 rows   go
```

Comment: What do you mean by "first value"? For example, if the file reads "foo.123", is "foo.123" the first value? Or is "foo." the first and "123" the second? Or what? You need to specify what you want with sufficient precision, otherwise the only useful answer you can get is "implement exactly whatever it is that you want".

Comment: the first would be foo then it's be 123 like this: edd 123 fed 1 dwd. i wanna see which is string and which is int.

Comment: So you want to read a series of strings delimited by whitespace and see which of them consist solely of digits?

Comment: I added and example of what a file might look like. Im reading it through the file extraction operator inFile >> x; so it should grab 2 from that file first i need to check if 3 is an int then move on to the next and see if thats a int. This is so I can properly place them in the appropriate var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, one is to simply read it as a string, and the try to parse it as an integer in your own code. If the parsing succeeds then you have an integer otherwise you have a string.

There are a few ways to parse a string, including (but not limited to):

- Using [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and the `>>` operator, and check the stream flags
- [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)
- Programatically check if all characters are digits, convert using normal decimal arithmetic.

---

Simple example using [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

```
std::string input;
if (std::getline(std::cin, input))
{
    try
    {
        std::size_t pos;
        int n = std::stoi(input, &pos);

        // Input begins with a number, but may contain other data as well
        if (pos < input.length())
        {
            // Not all input was a number, contains some non-digit
            // characters as position `pos`
        }
        else
        {
            // Input was a number
        }
    }
    catch (std::invalid_argument&)
    {
        // Input is not a number, treat it as a string
    }
    catch (std::out_of_range&)
    {
        // Input is a number, but it's to big and overflows
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use exceptions, then the old C-function [`std::strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) may be used instead:

```
std::string input;
if (std::getline(std::cin, input))
{
    char* end = nullptr;
    long n = std::strtol(input.c_str(), &end, 10);

    if (n == LONG_MAX && errno == ERANGE)
    {
        // Input contains a number, but it's to big and owerflows
    }
    else if (end == input.c_str())
    {
        // Input not a number, treat as string
    }
    else if (end == input.c_str() + input.length())
    {
        // The input is a number
    }
    else
    {
        // Input begins with a number, but also contains some
        // non-number characters
    }
}
```

Comment: did a little research on both stoi and istringstream. any chance you could give me and example of how this might work?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of doing this is by 1 character lookahead

```
int nextInt()
{
   std::stringstream s;
   while (true) 
   {
       int c = getch();
       if (c == EOF) break;
       putch(c); // remove if you don't want echo

       if isDigit(c) 
          s << (char)c;
       else if (s.str().length() > 0)
           break;        
   }

   int value;
   s >> value;
   return value;
}
```

You should be able to convert this example to repeat the process for all "words" in the file.

Comment: Basically, what you do is...  If I just got an int, and the next char is not an int (using peek) then drop an int to std out, and start reading a string.

Comment: I'm reading from a file not user input. say the file contained: tyyr    54   dhh i wanna use: myFile >> x to grab "tyyr" and check if it's a int. will that work with isdigit(x) or will i run into a compile issue because im trying to put a string into a int var?

Comment: @Duane: Don't 4get that nonnumbers can start with a digit.

Comment: @SaladSnake you would be reading a single character at a time.  Only place it in the digit when after you have checked isdigit.

Comment: I replaced the code with a much better example..  could re-work it to output a string too...